# "ab 10 Jahre" or "ab 10 Jahren"?

Tags: grammatical-case

I'm creating a flyer for an event that may be interesting for children from a certain age.  How do I express this correctly?  Is the event „geeignet für Kinder ab 10 Jahre“ or „geeignet für Kinder ab 10 Jahre**n**“?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely "ab 10 Jahre**n**". *Ab* does not license the accusative.